# Eclipse/Java source file issues with Lucene

Tags: java, eclipse

Everytime I run the following code in debug mode in eclipse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Index index = new Index();
    Thing t = new Thing();
    index.buildIndex(t);    
}
```

I get the following error (at the end of a massive stack trace):

'The source attachment does not contain the source for the file URLClassPath.class'

following the first line.

The Index class just uses the default constructor and has no private fields, just methods that build indexes of Things in memory.

The entire project is to be run on a Jboss server, but this is currently being run as a stand alone application (under a different run configuration).

The application loader can find src.zip in the java folder.

Has anyone else had similar problems? This only occurs when I try to debug and not when I run the application properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Index class is from Lucene and when you debug Eclipse is trying to find it.  You can get the correct Lucene source for whatever binary version you have, and then loo up "Eclipse attach source".

Comment: Lucene is in the build path - my code runs in run mode but not debug.